# Interpreting guitar tab notations (zeros, numbers, curve, arrow)

Tags: notation

I am a beginner at guitar. I was looking at a guitar tab for a Chinese song but I have trouble understanding it. x means to pick the string where it is drawn, but what do the other symbols mean in this context? Can anyone help me to interpret the action to be executed where there are zeros and the symbol that looks like y, and the 4 in the second line and 1st bar, and the curve in the second line and last bar. What do they mean? And does the arrow in the second line and last bar mean a strum starting from the 5th string?

Please advice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here is the guitar tab source: http://www.seotar.com/liuxing/760.html

Answer (score 1):

A bit of guesswork. Yes, the 'x' means play the string shown, whilst holding down the chord shown. The 'o' probably means play that string with no fingers on - open. The 'y' is most likely a quaver rest sign, meaning play nothing for that moment.The '--->' on the chord window will be a barre. Haven't a clue what the numbers under the staff are for, though.The arrow usually means a slow strum - an arpeggio, in the direction of the arrow.

Comment: The arrow I meant was the vertical arrow pointing up. Actually these are probably good resources for these kind of tabs (in Chinese): http://www.jitatang.com/kanpu.html

http://www.jitatang.com/pubiaoji.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Tims answer.
Looking at tabs on source you can see that there is a slide from 5 to seven on B and a hammer on 3 to 5
[image]